# How to create CRAN ready R package that has external dependency libxml2

Tags: r, cran, r-package

I have created an R package that I would like to submit to CRAN. It contains code that needs to be compiled in plain C and this code depends on the `libxml2` library.

My current solution is to let Linux and Mac users install the `libxml2-dev` package, which lets them compile and install the R source package.

For Windows, I have created a special binary R-package that contains the required binary dependency. When reading the CRAN guidelines I see that only source packages may be uploaded and that they may not contain any binary files.

After those guidelines, my questions are:

1. Is it ok for Mac/Linux to have the user install libxml2-dev prior to installing the R package or are there alternative solutions?
2. How should I do for Windows where the libxml2 is not straight forward to install for an end user?

Comment: This package by the world's most prolific R coder also has that dependency. Why not just copy what he did?  https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/xml2/index.html

Comment: Thanks for the link! I had already looked into that package but I missed the tools/winlibs.R that checks if libxml2 was included in Rtools or downloads it from here: https://github.com/rwinlib

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As mentioned above, you can just copy over what the [xml2](https://github.com/hadley/xml2) package does:

- To get things to work on Linux/MacOS, copy the files `configure` and `/src/Makevars.in`. Note that macOS includes a copy of libxml2 by default, so you can safely link to `-lxml2` as you would do on Linux.
- For Windows need to copy the files `src/Makevars.win` and `tools/winlibs.R` from xml2. This is a simple script that automatically downloads and statically links [libxml2 from rwinlib](https://github.com/rwinlib/libxml2) when building the R package on Windows.

These build scripts are tested to work on (almost) any platform.

Comment: Thanks for these pointers! Using these files (slightly modified for my particular package) I can build without hassle on both Linux and Windows (haven't tested Mac yet, but I assume it will work). One big step closer to submitting my package to CRAN.