# Releasing on CRAN an r-package dependent on "RGtk2" and external libraries

Tags: r, travis-ci, r-package

I am currently in the process of releasing this GITHUB packege on CRAN:

https://github.com/lbusett/MODIStsp
   , but I am encountering some issues which I hope someone can help me overcome ! (Sorry for the long message, but the problem is  difficult to explain briefly. *I hope you'll be willing to read to the end...* )

The problem I'm having derives from the fact that I'm using package  `gWidgetsRGtk2` to create a GUI. However, `gWidgetsRGtk2` depends on package `RGtk2`, which itself requires some external libraries to work. This leads to the following problems towards CRAN release:

### On Windows

If I keep `gWidgetsRGtk2` in the dependency list of my package, checking it in RStudio goes well. I get no NOTES nor WARNINGS (provided I have all dependencies installed).

> R CMD check results  0 errors | 0 warnings | 0 notes  R CMD check
>   succeeded

Also `build_win` passes with no problems

However, if I then try to install the package from github **, and even if `gWidgetsRGtk2` is already installed in my library,** installation fails. So, for example:

```
devtools::install_github("lbusett/MODIStsp", ref = 'feature/cran_rel_candidate')
```

always gives me the following error:

> Warning: Failed to load RGtk2 dynamic library, attempting to install
>   it. Please install GTK+ from
>   http://ftp.gnome.org/pub/gnome/binaries/win64/gtk+/2.22/gtk+-bundle_2.22.1-20101229_win64.zip
>   If the package still does not load, please ensure that GTK+ is
>   installed and that it is on your PATH environment variable IN ANY
>   CASE, RESTART R BEFORE TRYING TO LOAD THE PACKAGE AGAIN Error in
>   inDL(x, as.logical(local), as.logical(now), ...) :  unable to load
>   shared object
>   'C:/Users/lb/Documents/R/win-library/3.3/RGtk2/libs/x64/RGtk2.dll':
>   LoadLibrary failure:  Impossible to find.....

, and I get an information window telling me that "libaptk-1.0-0.dll"" is missing. Pressing "ok" on the message **sends me in an infinite loop of attempted installation of `RGTk2`** and I have to force-close RStudio.

The only way I managed to install the package correctly is by:

1. **Removing the `gWidgetsRGtk2` dependency** from my package;
2. Asking users to install `gWidgetsRGtk2` beforehand and load it at least once. (In that case, after the "libaptk-1.0-0.dll is missing" message, this info panel opens, allowing me to install GTK+ libraries)

[image]

So, for example, this:

```
install.packages("gWidgetsRGtk2")
library("gWidgetsRGtk2")
install_github("lbusett/MODIStsp", ref = 'devel')   # In devel, 'gWidgetsRGtk2'is not a dependency
```

works with no issues.

Asking the user to install the offending package beforehand is no big deal, **but I don't know if that is admissible for a CRAN package**, also because checking the package after removing the dependency gives me the following warning:

> checking dependencies in R code ... WARNING 'loadNamespace' or
>   'requireNamespace' call not declared from: ‘gWidgetsRGtk2’ R CMD check
>   results 0 errors | 1 warning  | 0 notes
>
> R CMD check succeeded

So, in the end my question is: **Do you know if there is a way to solve this problem, or how should I deal with it in the process of making a CRAN release ?**

## On Linux

On Linux the problem is related but a bit different.

1. First of all, package "RGTk2" requires some external libraries to be installed beforehand (Cairo >= 1.0.0, ATK >= 1.10.0, Pango >= 1.10.0, GTK+ >= 2.8.0, GLib >= 2.8.0). Also, I need to have "gdal" installed with hdf4 support.

Setting the following YAML file allows me to pass the checks on TRAVIS-CI (https://travis-ci.org/lbusett/MODIStsp/builds/168603035):

> ```
> language: r
> cache: packages
> warnings_are_errors: false
> matrix:
>   include:
>     - os: linux
>       dist: trusty
>       sudo: required
>       env:
>       global:
>         - R_BUILD_ARGS=" "
>         - R_CHECK_ARGS="--no-build-vignettes --no-manual --timings"
>         - R_CHECK_TIMINGS_="0"
>         - BOOTSTRAP_LATEX="1"    
>   addons:
>     apt:
>       packages:
>         - libgdal-dev
>         - libproj-dev
>         - libcurl4-openssl-dev
>         - libgtk-3-dev
>   r_binary_packages:
>     - cairoDevice
>     - RGtk2
> ```

what I don't know is **if/how/where I should specify these kind of dependencies for CRAN submission**. Can anyone explain this to me/point me to some reference ?

- The second problem is again related to `gWidgetsRGtk2` dependency. If I keep the dependency in, the build fails with this message ([https://travis-ci.org/lbusett/MODIStsp/builds/168600394](https://travis-ci.org/lbusett/MODIStsp/builds/168567126)):

> installing *source* package ‘gWidgetsRGtk2’ ... package
>   ‘gWidgetsRGtk2’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked R inst
>   tests preparing package for lazy loading R session is headless; GTK+
>   not initialized. (R:15669): Gtk-WARNING **: gtk_disable_setlocale()
>   must be called before gtk_init() Error : .onLoad failed in
>   loadNamespace() for 'cairoDevice', details:
>
> call: fun(libname, pkgname)   error: GDK display not found - please
>   make sure X11 is running   Error : package ‘cairoDevice’ could not be
>   loaded   ERROR: lazy loading failed for package ‘gWidgetsRGtk2’
>
> removing ‘/home/travis/R/Library/gWidgetsRGtk2’
>
> Error: Command failed (1)
>
> Execution halted
>
> The command "Rscript -e 'deps <-
>   devtools::dev_package_deps(dependencies =
>   NA);devtools::install_deps(dependencies = TRUE);if (!all(deps$package
>   %in% installed.packages())) { message("missing: ",
>   paste(setdiff(deps$package, installed.packages()), collapse=", "));
>   q(status = 1, save = "no")}'" failed and exited with 1 during .

As in the Windows case, the problem disappears if I remove `gWidgetsRGtk2` dependency, but then I get the WARNING in build/installation.

So, also in this case:  **Do anyone know how could I solve this ?**

Thanks in advance for any help ! (And thanks for reading ! )

Lorenzo

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39568937/how-to-create-cran-ready-r-package-that-have-external-dependencies-libxml2 The answer in this post may be help~